# Unity game - how to switch between pro and free back and forth

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here I am using unity normal. Normal unity doesn't provide build and run facility for Android

Now I also want to run, so I need to switch to the pro version which is free for 30 days. But how can I install second pro Unity if I am having normal one on my PC?

Answer (score 2):

You can manage licences selecting from the menu:

```
Help->Manage License
```

If you haven't still activated the 30 days pro version trial, you can activate it from there.